# Inserting newlines in Word using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I am using openxml WordProcessingDocument to open a Word template and replace placeholder  x1 with a string. This works fine unless I need the string to contain a newline. 
How can I replace x1 with text may contain newlines that word would recognise? I have tried \n \r but these do not work

Just to explain further when the word template is opened I read it into a StreamReader then use .Replace to replace x1.

Comment: It's not awesome but: `.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "</w:t><w:br/><w:t>")` might work for you.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: Any idea about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307691

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To insert newlines, you have to add a `Break` instance to the `Run`.

Example:

```
run.AppendChild(new Text("Hello"));
run.AppendChild(new Break());
run.AppendChild(new Text("world"));
```

The XML produced will be something like:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>Hello</w:t>
  <w:br/>
  <w:t>world</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: I don't think I can use your answer in my situation. I updated my question to explain further

Comment: So you're working with the XML directly? In that case, try inserting XML like the example.

Comment: Note, that in PPTX / PresentationML the `Break()` has to be child of the `Paragraph`, not child of the `Run`

Answer (score 32):

Here's a C# function that will take a string, split it on line breaks and render it in OpenXML.  To use, instantiate a Run and pass it into the function with a string.

```
void parseTextForOpenXML(Run run, string textualData)
{
        string[] newLineArray = { Environment.NewLine };
        string[] textArray = textualData.Split( newLineArray, StringSplitOptions.None );
        
        bool first = true;
        
        foreach (string line in textArray)
        {
            if(!first)
            {
                run.Append(new Break());
            }
            
            first = false;
            
            Text txt = new Text();
            txt.Text = line;
            run.Append(txt);
        }
}
```

Comment: niceeeee solution,thank's a lot, i use this solution when my string contains \n\r

Comment: Thanks, I modified `string[ ] newlineArray = { Environment.NewLine, "\n", "\r\n", "\n\r" }` to make it work for all type of break. 8 years past but still it's the best answer.

Answer (score 15):

Altough this question is already answered I have another approach to solve questions like :

**How can I make XXX with OpenXML??**

In this cases you could make use of the powerful **Microsoft OpenXML productivity tool** (also known as **OpenXmlSdkTool**). [Download here.](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5)

1. Create a new office document
2. Add the parts to the document which you would like to reproduce with OpenXML SDK.
3. Open the office document with **Microsoft OpenXML productivity tool**
4. Click on "Reflect Code"
5. On the right side you will see now you document reflected into C# code.

Comment: This is a great answer! I was after working out some tricky open xml bits and had to google the inner workings of almost every element. Having a tool which can output the trick bits and paste them in is a major timesaver, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I have the same issue and in my case `<w:br />` tag worked.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Tank you very much!