# How to insert a newline in PowerPoint (PPTX) in OpenXML / PresentationML / C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentationml

While Word and PowerPoint both use OpenXML, newlines are handled differently. In Word/WordprocessingML you can `run.Append(new Break())` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml)) to insert a newline. Unfortunately in PresentationML this leads to a nonvalid presentation and with errors when loading it in PowerPoint.

How to add a newline in the `TextBody` of a PowerPoint `Shape`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Open XML Productivity Tool of Open Office SDK 2.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) has this great *Reflect Code* tool to get C# code of whatever OpenXML file you have. But especially after much editing, the text in a presentation gets splitted in various `Run` elements and the *reflect code* isn't very compact. Here's an example of a `TextBody` of a `Shape`.

```
new TextBody(
  new A.BodyProperties(),
  new A.Paragraph(
    new A.Run( new A.Text("first line") ),
    new A.Break(),
    new A.Run( new A.Text("second line") )
  ),
  new A.Paragraph(
    new A.Run( new A.Text("new paragraph") )
  )
)
```

Note, the `Break` is child of the `Paragraph`, not child of a `Run` (as it is in *WordprocessingML*).

Note, that the `Break` makes a newline (Shift-Return in PowerPoint), if you want a new paragraph (Return in PowerPoint), you'll need a new `Paragraph`.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work anymore, do you know where can I find it?

Comment: @LionKing Simple internet search gives https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK