# How to get LineBreaks in a single Cell in EPPlus with RichText

Tags: c#, epplus

I use the following Code:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage()) {    
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");    
    var cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];

    var r1 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine1" + "\r\n");
    r1.Bold = true;
    var r2 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine2" + "\r\n");
    r2.Bold = false;

    package.SaveAs(...);
}
```

But in the Excel file the newLines are gone...

I tried also with "\n" and "\r" but nothing was working...

Comment: I think line breaks in openxml are `<br>`  Here's a similar question for Word https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml

Comment: OK, but how would the Code look like? If I just replace the "\r\n" with <br> the <br> appears as normal Text in the cell...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Here is a working sample:

```
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo)) {    
         var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");    
         var cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
         cell.Style.WrapText = true;
         cell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;

         var r1 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine1" + "\r\n");
         r1.Bold = true;
         var r2 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine2" + "\r\n");
         r2.Bold = false;

         package.Save();
     }
```

But I think I found a bug in the Lib: This Code is **NOT** working:

```
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo)) {    
         var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");    
         var cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
         cell.Style.WrapText = true;
         cell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;

         var r1 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine1" + "\r\n");
         r1.Bold = true;
         var r2 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine2" + "\r\n");
         r2.Bold = false;

         cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
         var r4 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine3" + "\r\n");
         r4.Bold = true;

         package.Save();
     }
```

When I get the same range again and add new RichText Tokens, the old LineBreaks are deleted... (They are actually converted to "\n" and this is not working in Excel.)

Answer (score 4):

The Encoding of new line in excel cell is 10.
I think you have to do someihing like thise:

```
var r1 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine1" + ((char)10).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo)) {    
         var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");    
         var cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
         cell.Style.WrapText = true;
         cell.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
         var r1 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine1" + "\n\n");
         r1.Bold = true;
         var r2 = cell.RichText.Add("TextLine2" + "\n\n");
         r2.Bold = false;
         package.Save();
     }
```