# vb.net & new line for Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, openxml

my application collects data, transforms it and then saves everything to a Word-document.
This is the code which gets the text and saves it to the word document:

```
     Dim DOCXPath as string="C:\\Test"
     SelectedIndex="Atlantic City"
     Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(DOCXPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
        ' Add a main document part.
        Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()
        mainPart.Document = New Document()
        Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
        Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
        Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())

        Dim justification As Justification = New Justification()
        justification.Val = JustificationValues.Center
        Dim paragraphProperties1 As ParagraphProperties = New ParagraphProperties
        paragraphProperties1.Append(justification)
        Dim paragraph As Paragraph = New Paragraph
        paragraph.ParagraphProperties = paragraphProperties1

        ''Loop through the rows
        For Each ActualRow As DataRow In DataTablePublication.Rows

            'Find the rows matching the Index
            If ActualRow.Item(RefDocPubIndex).ToString = SelectedIndex Then
                'Write bold
                Dim runProperties As RunProperties = run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
                run.AppendChild(New Text(HeaderCreator(ActualRow)))
                run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)

                'Write bold
                run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
                run.AppendChild(New Text(TextCreator1(ActualRow)))
                run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)

                run.AppendChild(New Text(TextCreator2(ActualRow)))
                run.AppendChild(New Paragraph)
            End If
        Next
        wordDocument.Close()
    End Using
```

The function TextCreator2 returns for example the following string:

```
"Atlantic City had 1 million inhabitants" + Environment.NewLine + "That is wrong!"
```

The part about the new line is the part which gets somehow "deleted" during the writing to the .docx-file. Can anyone explain me why and how I can solve this?

Comment: Suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml (AFAICS you are just inserted a newline character into a Word "run" 0 that won't work, at most you will see white space when you open the document. You need to insert the OOXML markup for a "break".

Comment: @jonsson: Your link suggestion is a good duplicate: [Inserting newlines in Word using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml)

Comment: For the solution given by the linked topic I have a "problem". My function returns the whole phrase. Where statement is instantly followed by the correct answer. So I tried inserting the  `<w:br/>` tag in every possible manner (`<w:br/>`, `<w:br />`, `< w:br />`) but nothing worked. Just to be assured: my OutputText would be: `OutputText="Atlantic City is flat.<w:br/>That is not true.`  or do I need to write something else? So that the `<w:br/>`-tag is not directly in the text?

Comment: The thing is that you can't just put a <w:br/> in the middle of a piece of text. You have to terminate the text first and restart it after, as per the suggestion by BrainSlugs83. My guess is that that suggestion is a bit of a kludge abd so may not work in all  circumstances.